# Is it possible to have the same CodeIgniter URI segment as a function parameter and a pagination parameter?

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-2

I've got a method `news()` which takes two optional parameters - `$category` & `$slug`.

The news page needs to show a paginated list of all of the uncategorised news articles (the Category page (with `$category` set) will need to do the same, but for the categorised subset).

Because of this, it seems that the standard pagination isn't working, as the 2nd URI segment is being seen as the `$category` parameter for `news()`.  Is it possible to work around this, perhaps treating the 2nd URI segment as the $category parameter if it isn't an integer, or the pagination parameter if it is?

Here are the relevant code pieces:

**Controller**

```
function news($category = null, $slug = null) {
    if($category == null) { // Get the standard "news" page

        // Define the pagination config
        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'news/';
        $config['total_rows'] =$this->post_model->count_posts('NWS');
        $config['per_page'] = 3;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        // Set the page info
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
        $data['newsPosts'] = $this->post_model->get_post_list_excerpt('NWS',$config['per_page'], $page);
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->template->load('default', 'newsview', $data);
    }
    elseif($slug == null) { 
        // Get the page specific to the chosen category
    }
}
```

To try and tidy up the URLs, I'm also using routing:

**routes.php**

```
$route['news'] = 'site/news';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'site/news/$1';
$route['news/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'site/news/$1/$2';
```

Is there a way round what I'm trying to do/is it even possible?  I'd like to avoid having to have separate methods/controllers (such as `news/categories/$category` if possible

Comment: How about [`is_numeric()`](http://us1.php.net/is_numeric): `if(is_numeric($category))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is some advice that you can consider.

1. You could use `base_url("site/news/");` instead of `base_url() . 'news/';` to give clarify to your code.
2. Make use of `news/(:any)/(:any)` regex at this case is ambiguous/incorrect because the first `(:any)` pattern is already containing all the rest of the url. What I mean:

   example.com/site/news/12/file

   - > $route['news/(:any)'] = 'site/news/$1';

     `$1` will match **12/file**
   - > $route['news/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'site/news/$1/$2';

     `$1` will match: **12/file**
     `$2` will match:  (nothing)

   Might you can conside to use some specific wildcard and give extra security to your urls:

   > **Note**: Remember to apply the rules from longest to shortest:

   ```
   $route['news/(:num)/([a-z]+)'] = 'site/news/$1/$2';
   $route['news/(:num)'] = 'site/news/$1';
   $route['news'] = 'site/news';
   ```

Now, coming back to the original question, I think you could inverse the params to let the `category` as **last one**. Let's see:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url("news/category/subset");
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

Take a look at this:

```
public function news($category = false, $subset = false, $page = 1)
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    //checks if category is the page number
    if ((string)(int)$category === $category)
    {
        //ok, there is not category neither subset
        $config['base_url'] = base_url('site/news');
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    }

    //checks if subset is the page number
    else if ((string)(int)$subset === $subset)
    {
        $config['base_url'] = base_url('site/news/' . $category);
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    }

    //by elimination, all the three parameters are presents
    else
    {
        //ok, both are presents
        $config['base_url'] = base_url('site/news/' . $category . '/' . $subset);
        $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
    }

    $config['total_rows'] = 200;
    $config['per_page'] = 20;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    // more stuff here
}
```

This pagination config should works with urls like:

- example.com/site/news/
- example.com/site/news/cat/
- example.com/site/news/cat/subset/

and page numbers:

- example.com/site/news/3
- example.com/site/news/cat/5
- example.com/site/news/cat/subset/3

Comment: Thanks, Manix.  I made the suggestion made in #2, and that's tidied things up a bit.  I also tried the final suggestion, but it hasn't worked.  The issue is that `category/subset` isn't always there.  The 2nd part of the URI segment can _either_ be the category, or the page number

Comment: can you let me know which parameters are optionals?  are you using default values for parameter with no values? For example, when the category is not present coult set it to `general`.

Comment: `$category` and `$slug` are optional parameters, and are blank when not set (i.e. `example.com/news/`)

Comment: thanks a lot!  I did a little tweaking to tidy up the URL (adding ` || $slug == null` after the various `if ((string)(int)$subset === $subset)` clauses so I didn't have to add /1 at the end of each url) and it works like a charm.